# Tkinter root window class inheritance, adding widgets in __init__

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am beginning with Tkinter, trying to make a simple root window with an horizontal button bar in the upper side of the window and a list of entries in the rest of the window.

When debugging this step by step I find that this line:

```
            _button_widget = tk.Button(self.button_bar, title=_button_label)
```

makes the **init** method to return back to main closing the window.
Sidenote: I can not see any exception raised (using Visual Code Studio as IDE) and Python 27. If I remove the buttons part the window is created and displayed.

**main.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import display_commander

def main():
    dc = display_commander.DisplayCommander()
    dc.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**display_commander.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk

class DisplayCommander(tk.Tk, object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DisplayCommander, self).__init__()

        self.geometry("350x150+150+150")

        # Button bar
        self.button_bar = tk.Frame(self)
        self.button_bar.config(bg="red")
        self.button_bar.pack()

        # Buttons
        self.buttons = []
        for _button_label in ['New Window', 'Delete Window', 'Save Config', 'Load Config']:
            _button_widget = tk.Button(self.button_bar, title=_button_label)
            _button_widget.pack()
            self.buttons.append([_button_label,_button_widget])

        # Window List
        self.window_list = tk.Frame(self)
        self.window_list.config(bg="yellow")
        self.window_list.pack()
```

Comment: This code should definitely throw an exception which would be helpful to you. You might need to look at how your "Visual Code Studio" IDE is configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `title` parameter cannot work for buttons, replace it by `text`:

```
_button_widget = tk.Button(self.button_bar, text=_button_label)
```

---

(I'm not sure how you want to use the `self.buttons` list in your code, maybe you have better options with a dictionary ? it can be easier to find/match a widget if you don't need a sorted structure storage.)

```
self.buttons = {}
    [...]
    self.buttons[_button_label] = _button_widget
```

Comment: Thanks I was not able to locate the issue. I am also surprised on why there is no exception raised (or at least I can't see it with Visual Code Studio). Regarding the dictionary it is a very good idea and thanks for going further with the advice. I am not sure if I will need it or not, once I add the button controllers I might even do not need dict or list at all.

Comment: PyCharm throws a nice `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-title"`. It can be convenient to have your own storage, it really depends on the logic of the next code